# SQL Missing Index DMV Where Equality Column is Null

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2014

I need some clarification on indexing a table (can't change structure).

I have a table: (That is essentially a hash table)

```
CREATE TABLE [lntmuid].[relatea](
[mid] [varchar](16) NOT NULL, 
[sid] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_relatea] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [sid] ASC, [mid] ASC ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample Data:

> ```
> ╔══════════════════╦══════════════════╗
> ║       mid        ║       sid        ║
> ╠══════════════════╬══════════════════╣
> ║ #19E29E4BB02C845 ║ A61469C1C8CBE629 ║
> ║ #19E29E4BB02C845 ║ CE6129BDC4580933 ║
> ║ #22659E4B4DB0976 ║ A61469C1C8CBE629 ║
> ║ #22659E4B4DB0976 ║ CE6129BDC4580933 ║
> ║ #22659E4B528C523 ║ A61469C1C8CBE629 ║
> ║ #22659E4B528C523 ║ CE6129BDC4580933 ║
> ║ #22659E4B5B74921 ║ A61469C1C8CBE629 ║
> ╚══════════════════╩══════════════════╝
> ```

And two non clustered indexes

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_mid_inc_sid] ON [TimeMatters].[lntmuid].[relatea] ([mid]) INCLUDE ([sid])
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_sid_inc_mid] ON [TimeMatters].[lntmuid].[relatea] ([sid]) INCLUDE ([mid])
```

This seams to be indexed from every angle but when I check the missing index DMV I get

[image: Missing Index]

What is it asking for when the equality column is blank ?  Is this because of the clustered index having two keys ?

I would appreciate any insight, knowledge, or advice.

Thank you so much

Comment: Why you are having two indexes with same structure,is it a typo.Further can you share the query

Comment: @TheGameiswar Thanks I fixed it.  It's a third party app most of the usage is actually cursors not queries.

Comment: Don't get stuck in the trap of implementing everything the missing indexes DMV suggests. It does a reasonably decent job most of the time but not always. You say this thing is "heavily indexed" but there are only two columns. And those two columns make up the composite key. Then you have to other indexes covering those same two columns from both directions. This seems over-indexed to me as it is.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not really in a hurry to add any indexes I'd like to know why even tho `[IX_sid_inc_mid]` already exists that it is asking for it in the DMV.  And also what an index without an equality column is ?  Thanks for the insight

Comment: Because that DMV suggests really crappy things about as often as not. It is not unusual that the view will produce suggestions for indexes that already exist. Take absolutely everything that view returns with an entire shaker of salt. You can read some more about the details of the results here. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345434%28v=sql.110%29.aspx